# Can anyone let me know the wrong in htaccess code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` code not working for clear cache and not hiding the extension like HTML. Please advise me where I did wrong.

```
Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file doing anything? (Is it enabled in the server config?) What URL are you requesting?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite , My website is a static website. My website working fine after added above mentioned lines but whenever we add new content, it's not showing properly. But if we clear the cache in the browser, it's showing properly. Also still it's showing . html

Comment: Please add the relevant HTTP response headers to your question. What is the URL you are requesting?

Comment: Your comment " Also still it's showing . html " suggests that you are trying to remove that "file name extension" from your URLs. The rewriting rule you posted does not attempt such thing, though. It only tries to rewrite _incoming_ requests without such extension.